# UIImage position

Tags: xcode, uiimage

I'm using the following code to place some images in the UIView:

```
UIImage *image;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480, 320));
int k=0;
int posY=0;

for (int i=0; i<[theArray count]; i++) {

    image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    if (k>2) {
        k=0;
        posY++;
    }       

    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(k*64, posY*23)];

    k++;

}


UIImage *combinatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Obtaining this result:

[image: http://cl.ly/8bSP]

But I would like to obtain this:

[image: http://cl.ly/8c6Q]

I can't figure out, I am so confused.

Can somebody help me, please???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an X offset to your last line of images if it has less than three:

```
for (int i=0; i<[theArray count]; i++) {

    int imagesLeft = min(3, [theArray count] - i);
    int offs = (3 - imagesLeft) * 64 / 2;

    for (int k = 0; k < imagesLeft; k++) {
        image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(k*64 + offs, posY*23)];
    }
    posY++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but your code generate this image http://cl.ly/8c8S but i would like something like this http://cl.ly/8bwO