# UIImage position

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIImage position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763678/uiimage-position)

I'm using the following code to place some images in the UIView:

```
UIImage *image;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480, 320));
int k=0;
int posY=0;

for (int i=0; i<[theArray count]; i++) {

    image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    if (k>2) {
        k=0;
        posY++;
    }       

    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(k*64, posY*23)];

    k++;

}


UIImage *combinatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

obtaining this result

http://cl.ly/8bSP

but i would like to obtain this:

http://cl.ly/8c6Q

i can't figure out, i am so confused. Can somebody help me, please??? thanks!!

**[SOLVED]**

This is my final working solution

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480, 320));

    int k=0;

    int posY=0;

    int d = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<[theArray count]; i++) {
        int imagesLeft = MIN(3, [theArray count]-i);
        image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theArray objectAtIndex:i]]];

        if (k>2) {
            k=0; 

            d=(3-imagesLeft)*32; 
            posY++; 
        }

        [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(k*64+d, posY*23)]; 

        k++; 
        NSLog(@"image nr. %i = %i",i,imagesLeft);
    }
    UIImage *combinatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Absolutely no research was done before asking the question!

Comment: Please don't crosspost, Filippo. Pick a single site to post on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're drawing the image at a position defined by

```
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(k*64, posY*23)];
```

When you go to the second row you reset k to zero.  So it's going to draw left-aligned, just like the first row.  You need to add a "delta":

```
int k=0;
int posY=0;
int delta = 0;

for (int i=0; i<[theArray count]; i++) {

image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
if (k>2) {
    k=0;
    posY++;
    delta = 30;
}       

[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(k*64 + delta, posY*23)];

k++;
}
```

Of course, this only works for five elements.  If you don't know how many elements you'll have in a row, you need to precompute that so that you only add the appropriate delta to the last row.

Comment: Your code works fine for the five elements as you said, but the elements, of course, can be more than five.

Comment: Well, like I said, you have to figure it out.  In your loop, when k = 0 (including the first time through), compute (theArray.count - i) % 3. If that value is 0 then delta = 0.  If 2 then delta = 30.  If 1 then delta = 64.  (Values approximate.)